# Browser that can't be managed by organization

Tags: web-browser

I need to block cookies in my browser to test solution to a bug. Unfortunately all IE,Edge,FF,Chrome browsers after install have status of being managed by an organization I need a browser that can't be.

Comment: What are you refering to with "have status of being managed by an organization"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/)

Follow the link to download for your environment - Windows, OSX, Linux or Android as required..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went with Vivaldi as ToR browser would probably be frowned upon in my organization.

Comment: your organisation will still be able to see the domains you are visiting though their network. they wont see the exact site but still. e.g. when you visit 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ' they will see 'https://www.youtube.com/'. For them to see nothing you have to use a vpn or proxy or a browser that uses Tor. So if it's just about the cookies this might be fine but you wont be anonymous or private.

Comment: @totalynotanoob Hiding sites was not the goal, I actually needed not managed browser to simulate user's behaviour and unusual browser settings to replicate issue.